# Remove single quotes around array

Tags: python, replace

I have data that looks like this:

```
minterms = [['1,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x'], ['x,x,x,x,1,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,1,x,x,x,x,x,x']]
```

and I want to remove the single quotes around each array to get this:

```
minterms = [[1,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x], [x,x,x,x,1,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,1,x,x,x,x,x,x]]
```

I have tried

```
mintermNew = minterms.replace("'", "")
```

and this doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:
Here is a snippet of my code giving a bit more context.

```
dontcares = []
mintermAry = []
for mindata in minterms:
    for mindataIdx in mindata:
        mintermAry.append(mindataIdx.split())
    print(SOPform(fullsymlst, mintermAry, dontcares))

return
```

I am using mindataIdx.split() to put the data into an array. MindataIdx is the data that looks like `[['1,x,x,x,x....']`.
Using `.split("")` as mentioned in the commends throws this error:

```
mintermAry.append(mindataIdx.split(""))
ValueError: empty separator
```

using `.split(" ")` yields no changes.

Edit 2:

The data is being read into a dataframe from a file. The first 4 rows I want to discard. I am using this method to do it.

```
df = df.replace('-', 'x', regex=True)
dfstr = 
df.to_string(header=False,index=False,index_names=False).split('\n')
dfArray = np.array(dfstr)
dfArrayDel = np.delete(dfArray,range(4), 0)
dfArrayData = np.char.lstrip(dfArrayDel)
splitData = np.char.split(dfArrayData)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're definitly doing somthing very wrong, as, there is no reason for there to be single quotes around the contents of an array. Is this a string you're working with? Please elaborate.

Ill have to assume you want to split the string in the array up into separate elements by the commas, in which case you would want this -

```
miniterms.map(s => s[0].split(","));
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that this is python. The data is being read in from a csv file into a pandas data frame and that is why the data has the single quotes around it. I've done a bunch of massaging to it to get it to the ['1,x,x,x,...'] format and my last step is to remove the quotes.

Comment: Is this an XY Problem? What was the format of the data originally?

Comment: See edit #2. I read the data from file into a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if your writing in python or js, regardless your problem is that your 2d array contains only a single String, hence why it's all wrapped in quotes. If the String in your inner arrays were split into individual elements they would look like this:

```
[[1,'x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x'...], ['x','x','x','x',1,'x'...]]
```

`1` is a Number and therefore not wrapped in quotes while `x` is a char or String and therefore is wrapped in quotes. These quotes are there only to visualize the variable datatype and are not part of the variable value itself. As the quotes don't exist they can't be removed (eg by using replace)

If your String, before putting it in an array looks like this.

`data = '1,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x'`

You can split it into an array like this:

`data_array = data.split("")`

Comment: Using .split("") actually throws an error for me. I will edit my original post.

Comment: You can't use `split()` on `mindataIdx` since it's already a list and not a String. You have to use `split()` to generate the array. `split()` splits a string into sections depending on the given separator creating an array of sections. If you want to perform split on a list you have to do it like this. `mindataIdx = mindataIdx[i][j].split("")`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to split mindataIdx by the comma to create individual items, and then it was able to be recognized by SOPform. Thanks!

```
dontcares = []
mintermAry = []
for mindata in minterms:
    for mindataIdx in mindata:
        mintermAry.append(mindataIdx.split(","))
    print(SOPform(fullsymlst, mintermAry, dontcares))
```